# css hover with selenium 2.20+

Tags: java, css, selenium, hover

I want to activate the :hover class defined in css using selenium. This isn't new obviously but all suggested methods by previous threads don't work anymore.

Thinks I have tried (unsuccessfully)

- `Selenium`-Interface (using `WebDriverBackedSelenium`) and `mouseOver`
- `Actions` using `moveToElement(..).build().perform()`
- The `RenderedWebElement` is deprecated since 2.20 but I can't find a replacement for the `hover()`  method it provided.

Any ideas how to do it this time?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution which was mentioned by Mark Collin [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/oxmxWe-Roro). Worked for me..

```
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Appliances')]"));
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```

Comment: Thanks, that is even another method I didnt consider yet. The cause for this behavior however was that I disabled native events for my driver for former incompatibilities. After activating them again, all of the methods described actually work.